# Android notification(when the app is open)

Tags: android, notifications, android-service, android-notifications

I use this code in android service to send notifications:

```
notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "title", "text", pendingIntent); 
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
notificationManager.notify(id, notification);
```

This code works fine if the app is closed, but I do also want that it also sends notifications when the app(any activity of the app) is open, when the app is open, I am not receiving the notifications.  So please tell me what to do to receive notification even if the app is open.

Answer (score 0):

Not works for me...
with

```
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE | Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR
```

the notification remain and do not disappear after tapping.

I've followed this tutorial http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-send-push-notifications-using-gcm-service/ and all works fine but when the app is opened and i tap on the notific arrived, nothing appears....

```
private void sendNotification(String trmMsg,String user, int role) {
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    resultIntent.putExtra("trmjson", trmMsg);
    resultIntent.putExtra("fragment", "readN");
    resultIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    resultIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder;
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    String msg = role == 1 ? user + " conferma il cambio di turno!" : "Attenzione, cambio di turno!";

    mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("TRM")
            .setContentText(msg)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notific);
    mNotifyBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    int defaults = 0;
    defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
    defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

    mNotifyBuilder.setDefaults(defaults);
    mNotifyBuilder.setContentText(msg);
    mNotifyBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    mNotificationManager.notify(notifyID, mNotifyBuilder.build());
}
```

Comment: I've solved using System.exit(0) after mNotificationManager.notify(notifyID, mNotifyBuilder.build()); but i know that is not the right solution...